# Autowiring: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring

I've tried about 50 potential solutions in like 5 duplicate questions, nothing has worked. What I'm trying to do should be excruciatingly simple. Simply trying to test a class....

The main advice seems to be to properly annotate with `Component`, and I have tried many versions of this.

I suspect it might have to do with the test not being able to "find" the class, since they are in different parts of the project, although I've tried putting in `ComponentScan` and it hasn't worked. I believe this project structure is conventional:

```
src:
  main:
    java:
      com.projectname.location.api.services:
        LocationService
        LocationServiceImpl
  test:
    java:
      com.projectname.location.api.services:
        LocationServiceTest
```

The interface:

```
package com.projectname.location.api.services;

public interface LocationRepository {

    /**
     * Read a CSV file to get IP addresses and locations.
     */

    void readCSV();

}
```

The implementation:

```
package com.projectname.location.api.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component("locationRepository")
public class LocationRepositoryImpl implements LocationRepository {

    @Override
    public void readCSV() {
        String csvFile = "path_to_csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine())) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println(country);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
package com.projectname.location.api.services;

import com.projectname.location.api.services.LocationRepository;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComponentScan("com.projectname.location.api")
public class LocationRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("locationRepository")
    private LocationRepository locationRepository;

    @Test
    public void testReadCSV() {
        System.out.println("wow");
        locationRepository.readCSV();
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.projectname.location.api.services.LocationRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'locationRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.projectname.location.api.services.LocationRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="locationRepository")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.projectname.location.api.services.LocationRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="locationRepository")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace, please?

Comment: How about removing the RunWith annotation, removing the ComponentScan, removing Autowired, and creating your class instance by yourself using `new LocationRepositoryImpl()`? You don't need Spring to create an instance of a class in order to unit-test it.

Comment: Instead of @ComponentScan, could you try with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = LocationRepository.class)` ?

Comment: @Villat i get the same error.

Comment: @JBNizet that works, thanks. I may need to incorporate Spring in this test class down the line though.

Comment: As JBNizet pointed out, you dont need to initialize the Spring Context and Autowire a bean to properly unit test. However, if you are trying to implement an Integration Test, you'll certainly want to use RunWith.

Comment: @MattTakao and removing the `@ComponentScan` and using `@SpringBootTest` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@SpringBootTest` to load an application context to be used in your tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LocationRepositoryTest {

    //Your tests

}
```